# Why does the C++ standard library prefer templates over enums?

Tags: c++, templates, enums, std

As per https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/execution_policy_tag, namespace `std::execution` defines compile-time constants of individual types:

```cpp
inline constexpr std::execution::sequenced_policy seq { /* unspecified */ };
inline constexpr std::execution::parallel_policy par { /* unspecified */ };
inline constexpr std::execution::parallel_unsequenced_policy par_unseq { /* unspecified */ };
inline constexpr std::execution::unsequenced_policy unseq { /* unspecified */ };
```

These values are used to parameterize other functions to use different modes.

An alternative implementation of this may look like this:

```cpp
enum class policy {
    seq,
    par,
    par_unseq,
    unseq,
};
```

I would potentially see two benefits of the former over the latter but both do not hold:

1. You are able to define individual overloads of a function based on this parameter; this is, however, not what is done in practice: `std::for_each` has `template<typename ExecutionPolicy, ...>`
2. It is extensible: an enum cannot be extended by the user but a user can always define their own structs and this is often allowed throughout the standard library, e.g., through template specialization; this does not apply here, though, as the implementation details are unspecified by the standard library; as such, it is not possible to create your own standards-compliant type

The major downside of the standard library's approach is that it turns the consuming functions into templates and thus make everything inline, compile slower, etc.

What is the reasoning of using separate types over an enum when an enum could do the job just as well? Are there any examples of predefined enums in the standard library?

When writing my own library, should I mimic this convention or opt for enums when possible?

Comment: "Why does the C++ standard library do <X>?" frequently boils down to flexibility. I suspect that is the answer here.

Comment: Different types participate in overload resolutions, enums do not.

Comment: Also note (besides 273K's answer) that you can have something very similar to foreach over types in recent c++: a template-lambda can loop over a template parameter pack.

Comment: @273K that is true, but it is not what is done in practice. You can pass the enum as a `constexpr` parmeter as well, if you truly wanted: `template<policy_enum ExecutionPolicy> void f() {}` (and then `constexpr if`)

Comment: @lorro could you link me the looping over parameter packs? Sounds interesting

Comment: @PostSelf _"The major downside of the standard library's approach is that it turns the consuming functions into templates and thus make everything inline, compile slower, etc."_ This argument doesn't hold if you're suggesting using the enum as a template parameter.

Comment: `template<policy_enum ExecutionPolicy> void f{}` non typed templates do not deduce template parameter values.

Comment: With `enum` function parameter you'll have to pay for run-time checks of an enum value inside a function. With tag function parameter a function will be selected at compile-time. If you need run-time flexibility, you can do it yourself on top of compile-time tags. If you don't want to pay it, with `enum` you'll have no choice. And yes, [we do have](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/launch) enums in the standard library.

Comment: Evg have said it better than me in my last comment.

Comment: @PostSelf Say you have `template<typename... Ts>` and `std::tuple<Ts...> tpl` in arguments (or something similar), then you can do `[&]<size_t... is>(std::index_sequence<is...>) { return ([&](auto arg) { /* do something with arg, return true to continue */ }(std::get<is>(tpl)) && ...); }(std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts)>());`, or something similar (pls forgive any typos, this is a comment box - can give more polished answer in a distinct question).

Comment: The non-parallel versions of the parallel algorithms are templates, so defining the parallel policy arguments as distinct types does not “turn the consuming functions into templates”.

Answer (score 2):

The standard library algorithms are templates anyway, so there is no potential for any difference in that regard.

The only benefit of using the enum approach with all policies sharing the same type would be that the policy can be chosen easily at runtime. However, the choice of policy must be coordinated with the types/algorithms used anyway. It is unlikely that this would be useful.

All else being equal it is preferable to use a different type for each policy so that there is more information available at compile-time. It is always possible to discard compile-time information in the implementation if that is desired, but the reverse is not possible.

Regarding your points:

1. Just because the standard specifies only one overload doesn't mean that the implementation must use only one overload. The standard library implementation is allowed to use as many overloads as it wants.
2. It is not allowed to specialize or overload standard library functions anyway.

Comment: Thanks, those points make sense. The thoughts on run-time choice are interesting and I will thus opt for enum for my own library. One note: you are allowed to specialize templates in namespace `std`: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std

Comment: @PostSelf Specializing _class_ templates is (usually) allowed. Specializing _function_ templates is not.